# I'm trying to draw CSS animation lines that aren't rendering

Tags: html, css, css-animations

As the title suggests, I am trying to create an animation that draws an infinite line loop around a button I have created yet it isn't rendering for some reason. Below is my CSS and HTML Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="pathway-box">
<body>
  
    <h2>Which Person Are You Looking For?</h2>
    <form>
      <a href ="/home/chimera/Documents/k13c/fail/jr/index.html" class="Jr">Jr</a>
      <a href="#" class="Sr">Sr</a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@700&display=swap');

html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(22,22,85,1) 19%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  }
  
  .pathway-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .pathway-box h2 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
      margin: 40px;
  }

.pathway-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
.pathway-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}
  
  
  .pathway-box form a {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px
  }

  .pathway-box a:hover {
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 25px #03e9f4,
                0 0 50px #03e9f4,
                0 0 100px #03e9f4;
  }


  .pathway-box a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }

  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim1 {
    0% {
      left: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      left: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .25s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim2 {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      top: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .5s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim3 {
    0% {
      right: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      right: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .75s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim4 {
    0% {
      bottom: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      bottom: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  

  .Jr{
    left: 50px;
  }

  .Sr{
    left: 140px;
  }
```

I have tried changing it such that the lines are rendered at all but to no avail and can't find how to get them to render, my code is a fork of [this](https://codepen.io/soufiane-khalfaoui-hassani/pen/LYpPWda?editors=1100) and I am trying to create the animation around the submit button on both the Sr and Jr buttons showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to add **"span"** tag inside the **a** tag.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Quicksand:wght@700&display=swap');

html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(22,22,85,1) 19%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
  }
  
  .pathway-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 40px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 15px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
  
  .pathway-box h2 {
    margin: 0 0 30px;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
      margin: 40px;
  }

.pathway-box .user-box input:focus ~ label,
.pathway-box .user-box input:valid ~ label {
  top: -20px;
  left: 0;
  color: #03e9f4;
  font-size: 12px;
}
  
  
  .pathway-box form a {
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: #03e9f4;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: .5s;
    margin-top: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 4px
  }

  .pathway-box a:hover {
    background: #03e9f4;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #03e9f4,
                0 0 25px #03e9f4,
                0 0 50px #03e9f4,
                0 0 100px #03e9f4;
  }


  .pathway-box a span {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }

  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim1 1s linear infinite;
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim1 {
    0% {
      left: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      left: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(2) {
    top: -100%;
    right: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim2 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .25s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim2 {
    0% {
      top: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      top: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(3) {
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: linear-gradient(270deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim3 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .5s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim3 {
    0% {
      right: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      right: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  .pathway-box a span:nth-child(4) {
    bottom: -100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient(360deg, transparent, #03e9f4);
    animation: btn-anim4 1s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: .75s
  }
  
  @keyframes btn-anim4 {
    0% {
      bottom: -100%;
    }
    50%,100% {
      bottom: 100%;
    }
  }
  
  

  .Jr{
    left: 50px;
  }

  .Sr{
    left: 140px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<div class="pathway-box">
<body>
  
    <h2>Which Person Are You Looking For?</h2>
    <form>
      <a href ="/home/chimera/Documents/k13c/fail/jr/index.html" class="Jr">Jr
       <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="Sr">Sr
       <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      </a>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You rock star. <3 I don't understand why I needed the spans though.